# Return Least Value Greater than Zero from Same Row in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the least of prices from different suppliers and the name of the supplier. The least should be greater than zero(0). I have been able to get minimum value if zero is not in the list. For instance, based on the code below, i want to be able to select 17 as minimum price instead of 0 and sup3 as the supplier.
see my code below:

```
SELECT least(sup1,sup2,sup3,sup4,sup5) AS mininumValue,
       (CASE least(sup1, sup2, sup3, sup4, sup5)
            WHEN sup1 THEN 'sup1'
            WHEN sup2 THEN 'sup2'
            WHEN sup3 THEN 'sup3'
            WHEN sup4 THEN 'sup4'
            WHEN sup5 THEN 'sup5'
        END) as Supplier 
FROM price_charts  
WHERE partno = 'OL0002';
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is somewhat painful in MySQL.  One method is to unpivot the data, filter and aggregate.  Another is to do some tricks.

Unfortunately, `LEAST()` returns `NULL` if any value is `NULL`.  But you can use a magic value:

```
select least(coalesce(nullif(sup1, 0), 999999),
             coalesce(nullif(sup2, 0), 999999),
             coalesce(nullif(sup3, 0), 999999),
             coalesce(nullif(sup4, 0), 999999),
             coalesce(nullif(sup5, 0), 999999)
            ) as minimumValue,
       (case least(coalesce(nullif(sup1, 0), 999999),
                   coalesce(nullif(sup2, 0), 999999),
                   coalesce(nullif(sup3, 0), 999999),
                   coalesce(nullif(sup4, 0), 999999),
                   coalesce(nullif(sup5, 0), 999999)
                  )
            when sup1 then 'sup1'
            when sup2 then 'sup2'
            when sup3 then 'sup3'
            when sup4 then 'sup4'
            when sup5 then 'sup5'
       end) as Supplier 
from price_charts pc 
where partno = 'OL0002';
```

Note:  You have a poor data model.  You should have another table with one row per supplier and price, not pivoting the values into separate columns.

Comment: Thanks,I tried using nullif but i got stuck when retiriving the supplier that matches the minimum price. This works. But the other issue is that it return  magic value when all the prices are zeros. I thought it will return the first column or what do you think.

Comment: @Dave . . . You can add an additional condition to avoid the magic value.